# Sorted int[] Converted from String[] -- ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, split, indexoutofboundsexception

**CONTEXT**

I've been trying to fix this part of my program for a while now without much success. I essentially want to sort a `String []` where each element is in the format: `name:number` (i.e. `john:32`).

**PROGRESS**

So far, my code splits each element and adds it to an equivalent `int []`. I then attempt to compare the elements in the `int []` with *selection sort* and swap the elements in the `String []`.

**PROBLEM**

I'm getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for my `String []`, which is called `scores`. Why is this?

```
scores = sort(scores); //ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException here


public static String [] sort(String [] A) {


        //equivalent array containing only integer part of score[i]
        int[] tempArray = new int[A.length];

        //populate tempArray
        for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            //acquire numerical part of element
            //ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException here********
            int num = Integer.parseInt(A[i].split(":")[1]); 
            //add to array
            tempArray[i] = num;
        }


        /* Selection Sort: descendinG */

        //compare elements (integer) in tempArray
        for(int i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++){
        int index = i;


            //search for integers larger for above index
                for(int j = i+1; j < tempArray.length; j++ ){
                    if(tempArray[j] > tempArray[index]){
                        index = j;
                    }}

                //swap elements in scores-array (String)
                String temp = A[index];
                A[index] = A[i];
                A[i] = temp;
        }

        return A;
    }
```

Comment: Evidently you have a string without `":"`.

Comment: Wooow... how did you know?

Comment: It was the only possibility.

Comment: Still trying or already solved?

Comment: Solved, I had a blank line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @shmosel

This can probably help you rooting out the bad apple

```
String scoreSplit[] = A[i].split(":");
if (scoreSplit.length() == 2){
   int num = Integer.parseInt(A[i].split(":")[1]);
}
else{
   system.out.println("Bad apple with "+ scoreSplit[0]);  //some kind of logging
}
```